# Jenkins Build Name Setter Plugin does not find variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins I use a parameterized build. I use the "This build is parameterized" and "List subversion tags" to which I set the "Name" to be SVN_TAG. Then I set this SVN_TAG in "Set Build Name" to "${SVN_TAG}". However, the build then says "Unrecognized macro 'SVN_TAG' in '${SVN_TAG}'" and it does not set the build name. Any ideas to why the build doesn't find this macro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you click on the `(?)` help icon next to the Build Name field, you'll see a list of the macros you can use.

Build parameters are exported as environment variables during the build, so as per that documentation, you need to use the format `${ENV,var="VARIABLENAME"}`.

So using the value `${ENV, var="SVN_TAG"}` should give you the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: this was it, thanks! I didn't get it at first because to the SVN repository url I only defined ${SVN_TAG}

Comment: Right. I expanded the answer a bit to mention that build parameters are exported as environment variables.