# How to use build name setter plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Does anyone know if there is a user manual somewhere on how to use the build name setter plugin for jenkins? The jenkins plugin website just seems to have a link to download the plugin and no information on how to use it. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed no official user guide for this plug-in.

However, clicking the [image] icon near this plug-in controls will provide you all the information you need (click **[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECMm3.jpg)** to see the image below in full resolution):

[image]

Comment: How did you get to that view?

Comment: This is available in the build configuration under the **Build Environment** section.

Comment: I'm on Jenkins 1.559. I don't see anything like that accessible from the dashboard. Is that a new section?

Comment: You need to click on '?', it'll display formatting help then.

Comment: Are parameterised build parameters available to the name setter plugin? I modified the build name to `#${BUILD_NUMBER} - ${PARAMETER}`, but I still only get the build number (not even the ` - `). Is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: Ah.. this answers my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071462/jenkins-build-name-setter-plugin-does-not-find-variable