# Can not find "build name setter" plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

as mentioned in [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111298/how-to-use-build-name-setter-plugin) I can't see the plugin as well.
There is no view in Build Environment.

Using Jenkins 1.648 and Build Name Setter 1.5.1 and german lanugage Setting.

Thanks Joerg

Comment: update: even no '?' to press!!

Comment: Why did you ask this question again when it's already been answered ?

Comment: Do not ask the same/similar question that is already been answered.

Comment: This is a valid question. The solution to the other question does not work for us. I'm having the same issue. The plugin is installed, but it does not show up under the 'Build Environment' as the similar link. I don't think he should be down voted for this. The other question was marked solved, indicating that he needed to click on the ?. But in my case, and OP's case, there is no ? to click on. If he made this comment on the other ticket, he would be directed to ask a new question and not look for help in comments of a separate one.

Comment: I have the same version of Build Name Setter and the same version of Jenkins. I've tried restarting after installing the plugin, and it's still not showing up. I believe this may be a valid compatibility issue with the Build Name Setter plugin and the current version of Jenkins.

Comment: I ask this question because of the given solution does not work for my Setup.

Comment: I also had this problem. It appears that in version 1.5.1 the 'Token Macro Plugin' also must be installed for it to work. I also had to restart Jenkins to get the build environment section to show up. I'm using Jenkins v1.651.